# Python regex negating metacharacters

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

Python metacharacter negation.

After scouring the net and writing a few different syntaxes I'm out of ideas.

Trying to rename some files. They have a year in the title e.g. [2002].
Some don't have the brackets, which I want to rectify.

So I'm trying to find a regex (that I can compile preferably) that in my mind looks something like `(^[\d4^])` because I want the set of 4 numbers that *don't* have square brackets around them. I'm using the brackets in the hope of binding this so that I can then rename using something like `[\1]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to check for things around a pattern you can use *lookahead* and *lookbehind* assertions.  These don't form part of the match but say what you expect to find (or not find) around it.

As we don't want brackets we'll need use a *negative* lookbehind and lookahead.

A negative lookahead looks like this `(?!...)` where it matches if `...` does not come next.  Similarly a negative lookbehind looks like this `(?<!...)` and matches if `...` does not come before.

Our example is make slightly more complicated because we're using `[` and `]` which themselves have meaning in regular expressions so we have to escape them with `\`.

So we can build up a pattern as follows:

- A negative lookbehind for `[` - `(?<!\[)`
- Four digits - `\d{4}`
- A negative lookahead for `]` - `(?!\])`

This gives us the following Python code:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile("(?<!\[)\d{4}(?!\])")
>>> r.match(" 2011 ")
>>> r.search(" 2011 ")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10884de00>
>>> r.search("[2011]")
```

To rename you can use [the `re.sub` function](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) or the `sub` function on your compiled pattern.  To make it work you'll need to add an extra set of brackets around the year to mark it as a group.

Also, when specifying your replacement you refer to the group as `\1` and so you have to escape the `\` or use a raw string.

```
>>> r = re.compile("(?<!\[)(\d{4})(?!\])")
>>> name = "2011 - This Year"
>>> r.sub(r"[\1]",name)
'[2011] - This Year'
```

Comment: wow, **thank you**. 2 [total noob] questions arise but perhaps I should start new threads.. why the ">>>" prompt and what is "at 0x10884de00" telling me ?

Comment: @Dee - The `>>>` prompt is there because I tested my code in the Python REPL; type `python` at a command line with no arguments and you can an interactive shell where you can run Python code one line at a time.  The value `0x10884de00` doesn't tell you anything.  What's significant is that `r.search(" 2011 ")` returned a match object so there was a match, but `r.search("[2011]")` returned nothing so there was no match.

Comment: Thank you, sir. And I'm happy to report that my first python program now has wings and has correctly renamed 100's of files according to my search/replace criteria. Many Thanks! hmm I can't seem to @ username